# MergedAnnotations Search Strategy failing after adding a dependency for com.graphql-java-kickstart

Tags: java, spring, graph, junit, graphql-java

I was trying to include graphql integration test cases in an already existing maven project using java *springframework v.4.1.0*,  for which I added library *com.graphql-java-kickstart » graphql-spring-boot-starter-test v.6.0.0*.

But after adding this, I got the following error for an existing and working test case:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/MergedAnnotations$SearchStrategy`

Could someone please help resolving this conflict. Is there some version of this library that is compatible with MergedAnnotations library of springframework. Or is there some other similar library available for implementing java graphql test cases. Also it will be very difficult to upgrade the springframework version because its a huge project and has a lot of dependencies.

I tried upgrading a few versions of *com.graphql-java-kickstart » graphql-spring-boot-starter-test*  but nothing really worked as some or the other part of the project was getting affected.Also tried upgrading springframework version but could not do so because of the libraries and dependencies included.